# WorkManager in AOSP

Tags: android, android-source, android-workmanager

Trying to use WorkManager in my SystemApp. I haven't been able to integrate it.

Android.mk :

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_PACKAGE_NAME := MySystemApp

LOCAL_CERTIFICATE := platform
LOCAL_PRIVILEGED_MODULE := true
LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional

LOCAL_JNI_SHARED_LIBRARIES := libloguploaderclient
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(call all-java-files-under, android/src)
LOCAL_RESOURCE_DIR := $(LOCAL_PATH)/android/res
LOCAL_STATIC_ANDROID_LIBRARIES := \
    androidx.core_core \
    androidx.annotation_annotation \ 
    androidx.work_work # This line doesn't work

LOCAL_PROGUARD_FLAG_FILES := android/proguard.cfg
LOCAL_PROGUARD_ENABLED := disabled
LOCAL_SDK_VERSION := current

ifeq ($(shell test $(PLATFORM_SDK_VERSION) -ge 28 && echo OK),OK)
  # Build as a vendor module
  LOCAL_PROPRIETARY_MODULE := true
endif

# Build as an Android app
include $(BUILD_PACKAGE)
```

The below part of the mk file doesn't work and giving bunch of compile error:

```
 LOCAL_STATIC_ANDROID_LIBRARIES := \
        androidx.core_core \
        androidx.annotation_annotation \ 
        androidx.work_work # This line doesn't work
```

So, how can I use WorkManager in AOSP?

Comment: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/prebuilts/sdk/+/refs/heads/android10-mainline-a-release/current/androidx/manifests/
I don't see worker, you need to add and use

Comment: @tadev thanks tadev. But how? Is there any aar file of work manager?

Comment: just add manifest and something like that https://android.googlesource.com/platform/prebuilts/sdk/+/refs/heads/android10-mainline-a-release/current/androidx/m2repository/androidx/viewpager/viewpager/1.1.0-alpha01

You can copy from your computer when you use it